# None of the git commands work on the Ubuntu terminal

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, terminal

I have been using `git` commands in the *ubuntu* terminal for a while without any problem. However, suddenly, none of the commands (e.g., `clone`, `pull`, `push`) working. When I hit `git pull`, the cursor does not do anything and waits.

Overall, the system looks healthy, it has access to the Internet and to the GitHub server when I ping.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Those are *git* commands, not GitHub. Also, if there is nothing to do, `git pull` will produce no output.

Comment: I edited his comment.  git pull will usually say "Already up to date." or some similar message if there is nothing to do.

Comment: There really isn't enough information to debug this, and I personally think it would be better suited for AskUbuntu.  That said, is there anything else you can tell us?  Have you tried purging and reinstalling git?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thanks for the reply. The problem is not `git pull` producing nothing, it halts and does not release the command line as if it is waiting for something. But I have access to the GitHub server.

Comment: Try `ssh git@github.com`. Does it work?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, no, same behavior

Comment: So your problem has nothing to do with `git`.  Try `nc -w 5 github.com 22`. Does it timeout after 5 seconds?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes it does

Comment: @user650261 I have not... I thought there might a known problem

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you clone a public repository?

Comment: Clearly his connection to GitHub is not working. Trying to pull repositories when he can't SSH is pointless. There's a network issue that needs fixed. I suspect some sort of firewall issue is blocking your TCP connection on port 22 while allowing your ICMP ping.

Comment: @user650261 No it also does not work

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I was curious if it was just ssh or all connections to github, hence the question for if he could clone.

Comment: That suggestion doesn't make any sense. If his repo URL starts with `git@github...` then every operation involves an SSH connection to GitHub.

Comment: If he clones using an https:// connection then it shouldn't use ssh.  For instance, https://github.com/tombh/texttop can be cloned at https://github.com/tombh/texttop.git.  This is the default url for this public repository.

Comment: Please add more information to your question.

Comment: `ssh -T git@github.com` will verify your connection (and SSH ability to connect) to GitHub.  Also read this:  https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally after trying many suggestions, I found the problem! The problem was that when I hit `git pull`, Ubuntu looks for my private key to communicate with GitHub server. But it was blocked since last time I discarded the message asking for password to access the private key. However, next time it no longer asked for the password. When I rebooted the system, I saw the message asking for accessing the private key again and when I entered the password, everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after a restart.

My issue was the same which brought me here when I entered

```
git status
```

OR

```
git branch
```

OR even

```
git --version
```

the command would return without any info or response. It gave me a bad command error when I entered a wrong command however.

So after landing here and reading @Sadegh's response, I finally got it fixed. There was a pending update and I did an 'Update and Restart'. After this I checked the specs of my PC, it had updated to:

```
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎29-‎Mar-‎21
OS build    19042.1110
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0
```

I don't know how to reproduce it, also not sure what was the previous build before I hit the upgrade and restart